# nth-of():before compatibility with Edge and Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm currently having an issue where the following works in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer but not on Safari and Microsoft Edge, for some reason in these two the style isn't being applied.

```
.legend-content ul li:nth-of-type(1):before{
color: #00b36a;
}
.legend-content ul li:nth-child(2):before{
    color: #ff9600;
}
.legend-content ul li:nth-child(3):before{
    color: #00ade5;
}
.legend-content ul li:nth-child(4):before{
    color: #d3cfd0;
}
```

[On Edge the stlye isn't being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcdfB.png), but Chrome has it just fine.

I've tried looking around but haven't found any compatibility issues with these browsers (and don't see why Edge would fail but IE wouldn't). So how would I go about to get a result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11GXM.png) in all browsers?

I should also mention that the lists have no style and the element before each li is:

```
.legend-content ul li:before{
    content: '◼ ';
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `content` property along with some other property which is required if `content` is not store any text value and `color` property work when you put any text in `content:"text"` with all `pseudo css element` like below code and it's working. Please add this and check.

```
.legend-content ul li:before{
   content: "■";
   font-size:18px;
}
.legend-content ul li:nth-of-type(1):before{
   color: #00b36a;
}
.legend-content ul li:nth-child(2):before{
  color: #ff9600;
}
.legend-content ul li:nth-child(3):before{
  color: #00ade5;
}
.legend-content ul li:nth-child(4):before{
  color: #d3cfd0;
}
```

Please see the attached image link below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6tmR.png

Comment: But content has text, it's the ASCII square ◼.

Comment: I have update my above code and you can see the working code in my attached screenshot link of **Edge browser**. Please make sure that the `content` property use with actual ASCII Square. If square is image format than it's not get the color on change so copy my code and paste and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

[I am not able to repreoduce the issue](https://jsbin.com/covujo/3), in Edge 15 or 16, though I did have to modify it slightly to include a content block to render

```
.legend-content ul li:before {
  content: 'number ';
}
```

The screenshot you posted is also what happens when you have a rule that is more specific than that rule. Its possible you have a edge specific or modernizr based css rule that is overriding. A rule that is not supported looks like this

[image: screenshot of edge dev tools with broken css syntax]

Comment: [I don't see a more specific rule, for some reason it's applying the body color, which doesn't make much sense to me] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/09hcE.png)

Comment: could you share a link to the page? It would be much easier to help that way